# systemctl status dovecot.service, it floods console with all logs, how to stop

Tags: linux, logging, systemctl

systemctl status dovecot.service, it floods console with all logs, how to stop it?
on my cpanel server, it is running through tailwatchd, and it eats up too much cpu, whenever it runs.

how to disable log output in service status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my cPanel server VPS.  For whatever reason dovecot tries to read every relevant long entry, in every journal file.  To solve this issue I moved all journal logs older than 7 days to an alternate location.

```
# mkdir /var/log/journal-old/
# find /var/log/journal/ -type f -mtime +7 -exec mv -v {} /var/log/journal-old/ \;
```

after that, restart your vps, or figure out which service is responsible for caching journal data, probably:

```
# systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
```